# What is Sahih al-Jami`?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, dua, books, islamic-scholar

A relative mailed me this du'a after my mother passed away last week.

> Whoever is stricken with sadness, grief, sickness or hardship and
>   says:
>   "Allahu Rabbi, la sharika lah" (Allah is my Lord, without any
>   partners), then it will be removed from him.”
>
> [‘Sahih al-Jami’ #6040]

I have heard that this (Sahih al-Jami) is a compilation by Sh. Al-Albani. Is there another title which is similar by another scholar or is this correct?

And in the compilation, does anyone know the source of this narration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original author is Imam as-Suyuti who wrote a book titled "Al-Jami` as-Saghir." Shaykh al-Albani the *muhaddith* investigated the hadith in this book and added some more and wrote "Sahih wa Da`if Al-Jami` as-Saghir wa Ziyadatuh" and marked the Sahih and Hasan *ahadith* from other kinds.

The hadith you quoted is indeed number 6040 in the Sahih portion of the book and is found in Al-Mu`jam al-Kabir of Tabarani narrated by Asma' bint `Umays.

Comment: After searching lots of places, I got the pdf version where some serials are missing. Is there any source where I can get all the hadiths of the book. I am in badly need of the Hadith no #881

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about this Hadees but I'd like to inform you about one more.

It is 'Inna Lillaahi Wa innaa Ilaihi Raji Oon. Allahumma' Jurni mi musibati wa akhlif lee khairam minha.
{Note: Its Allahumma' Jurni not Allahumma Ajurni or Ajirni}

Its Translation is "We belong to Allah and to Him do we return,
O Allah, reward me for my affliction and give me something better than it in exchange for it."

this Hadees is from [Mishkat al Masabih, #1618]
(Full Hadees below)
Umm Salamah reported God’s messenger as saying, “If any Muslim who suffers some calamity says what God has commanded him, ‘We belong to God and to Him do we return ; O God, reward me for my affliction and give me something better than it in exchange for it,’ God will give him something better than it in exchange.” When Abu Salama died she said, “What Muslim is better than Abu Salama whose family was the first to emigrate to God’s messenger? ”(He and his wife, Umm Salama, were among those who emigrated to Abyssinia. Abu Salama died of wounds received at the battle of Uhud, and the Prophet later married Umm Salama.) She then said the words, and God gave her God’s messenger in exchange.
Muslim transmitted it.
[Grade: Sahih (By Albaani)]

Answer (score -1):

Here is the haddith no #881
The hadeeth (saying) of Prophet Muhammad (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said:

“There are four (who will protest) to Allah on the Day of Resurrection: the deaf man who never heard anything, the insane man, the very old man, and the man who died during the fatrah (the interval between the time of Jesus and the time of Muhammad [peace and blessings of Allah be upon both of them]). The deaf man will say, ‘O Lord, Islam came but I never heard anything.’ The insane man will say, ‘O Lord, Islam came but the children ran after me and threw stones at me.’ The very old man will say, ‘O Lord, Islam came but I did not understand anything.’ The man who died during the fatrah will say, ‘O Lord, no Messenger from You came to me.’ He will accept their promises of obedience, then word will be sent to them to enter the Fire. By the One in Whose hand is the soul of Muhammad, if they enter it, it will be cool and safe for them.”

According to another report, he said: “Whoever enters it, it will be cool and safe for him, and whoever does not enter it will be dragged to it.” (The hadeeth was reported by Imam Ahmad and Ibn Hibban, and deemed sahih by al-Albani, Sahih al-Jami’, 881).